# How to set initial values in django forms.ChoiceField?

Tags: python, django

I have simple django form:

```
class AddSymbolForm(forms.Form):
    list_n = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)])
```

How can I set initial value in views.py?

I tried to something like this:

```
add_symbol_form = AddSymbolForm(initial={list_n:3})
```

And this is not working. So is there any way I can set initial values for choice fields?

P.S. It's interesing but this code set correct initial value

```
class AddSymbolForm(forms.Form):
    list_n = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)], initial=3)
```

and this one is not working correctly:

```
class AddSymbolForm(forms.Form):
    list_n = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)])
    list_n.initial = 3
```

Comment: In what way is your first snippet not working?

Comment: Apart from not being valid Python syntax (dict keys must be strings), the first one would work fine.

Answer (score 1):

you can set initial value in `get_initial()` in your view class, which comes from `FormMixin`, and it's a part of most generic views

```
    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        initial['list_n'] = 3
        return initial
```

example above has hardcoded value, but you should choose from `choices` and/or depend value from other conditions

Answer (score 0):

by default the first element of choices list would be the initial form value. try this:

```
class AddSymbolForm(forms.Form):
    list_n = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(3,3),(1,1),(2,2)])
```